# Changing font size in the nicheROVER package in R

Tags: r, font-size

I'm using the nicheROVER package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nicheROVER/nicheROVER.pdf) and vignette (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nicheROVER/vignettes/ecol-vignette.html#calculate-and-display-niche-overlap-estimates)

However, I can't figure out how to increase the font size for the niche.plot function

Here is the code in the vignette:

```
library(nicheROVER)
data(fish) # 4 fish, 3 isotopes
aggregate(fish[2:4], fish[1], mean) # isotope means calculated for each species type here
# 2-d projections of 10 niche regions
clrs <- c("black", "red", "blue", "orange") # colors for each species
nsamples <- 10
fish.par <- tapply(1:nrow(fish), fish$species,
                  function(ii) niw.post(nsamples = nsamples, X = fish[ii,2:4]))

# format data for plotting function
fish.data <- tapply(1:nrow(fish), fish$species, function(ii) X = fish[ii,2:4])

niche.plot(niche.par = fish.par, niche.data = fish.data, pfrac = .05,
          iso.names = expression(delta^{15}*N, delta^{13}*C, delta^{34}*S),
            col = clrs, xlab = expression("Isotope Ratio (per mil)"))
```

Does anyone know how I can increase the font? When I use this code for my own data, the font size is really small.

I did try including cex = 10 in the niche.plot() code, but got the error code:

```
Error in niche.plot(niche.par = fish.par, niche.data = fish.data,  : 
  unused argument (cex = 10)
```

I also tried using ggplot by doing:

```
p <- niche.plot(niche.par = fish.par, niche.data = fish.data, pfrac = .05,
          iso.names = expression(delta^{15}*N, delta^{13}*C, delta^{34}*S),
            col = clrs, xlab = expression("Isotope Ratio (per mil)"))
p + theme(text = element_text(size = 10))
```

but that also didn't work

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to reimplement the `niche.plot()` function because the default implementation does not include a `cex` argument which would be passed to the plotting functions.

Also, since `niche.plot()` uses base R plot and not ggplot2 (a completely different plotting system), your second solution does not work.

To reimplement `niche.plot()` you will need the source code of the function, which can be found on the package's [GitHub repository](https://github.com/mlysy/nicheROVER/blob/master/R/niche.plot.R). We can copy the function to our R script and add a `cex` argument with a default value of `cex = 1`. We then pass this value to the various functions that set text in the plot such as `mtext()` or `axis()`. Passing `cex` individually allows us more fine grained control over relative font sizes between axis labels, titles, etc. I'm passing the `cex` argument to various functions in lines 47, 87 - 90, 94 and 96 of the function. Everything else is as it is implemented in the `nicheROVER` package.

```
niche.plot <- function(niche.par, niche.data, alpha = .95,
                       species.names, iso.names, lims,
                       col, ndens = 512, pfrac = 0, xlab, cex = 1) {
  niso <- ncol(niche.par[[1]]$mu)
  nspec <- length(niche.par)
  npts <- 100 # number of points for each ellipse
  nell <- sapply(niche.par, function(x) nrow(x$mu)) # number of ellipses per species
  if(missing(species.names)) species.names <- names(niche.par)
  if(missing(iso.names)) iso.names <- colnames(niche.par[[1]]$mu)
  # create all the ellipses to get the plot limits right.
  ell <- vector("list", nspec)
  names(ell) <- names(species.names)
  D <- combn(niso, 2)
  for(ii in 1:nspec) {
    ell.tmp <- array(NA, c(nell[ii], ncol(D), npts+1, 2))
    for(jj in 1:nell[ii]) {
      for(kk in 1:ncol(D)) {
        ell.coord <- ellipse(niche.par[[ii]]$mu[jj, D[,kk]],
                             V = niche.par[[ii]]$Sigma[D[,kk], D[,kk], jj],
                             alpha = alpha, n = npts)
        ell.tmp[jj,kk,,] <- ell.coord
      }
    }
    ell[[ii]] <- ell.tmp
  }
  # plot limits.
  if(!missing(lims)) {
    # check that user didn't specify `col` positionally by mistake
    if(is.character(lims)) {
      stop("`lims` argument passed as a character vector.\nDid you mean to specify `col` instead?")
    }
  } else {
    # data
    lims <- array(sapply(niche.data, function(x) apply(x, 2, range)),
                  dim = c(2, niso, nspec))
    lims <- apply(lims, 2, range)
    # ellipse
    DD <- t(sapply(1:niso, function(ii) which(D == ii, arr.ind = TRUE)[1,]))
    elims <- array(sapply(ell, function(x) {
      tmp <- apply(x, c(4,2), range)
      rbind(as.matrix(tmp[1,,])[DD], as.matrix(tmp[2,,])[DD])
    }), dim = c(2, niso, nspec))
    elims <- apply(elims, 2, range)
    lims <- apply(rbind(lims, elims), 2, range)
  }
  # plots
  opar <- par(mfcol = c(niso,niso), mar = rep(.5, 4), oma = rep(4,4), cex = cex)
  for(ci in 1:niso) {
    for(ri in 1:niso) {
      # initialize plot
      plot.new()
      plot.window(lims[,ci], lims[,ri])
      if (ci == ri) {
        # diagonals: density plots
        xdens <- matrix(NA, ndens, nspec)
        ydens <- xdens
        for(ii in 1:nspec) {
          den <- density(niche.data[[ii]][,ci], n = ndens)
          xdens[,ii] <- den$x
          ydens[,ii] <- den$y
        }
        for(ii in 1:nspec) {
          ly <- par("usr")[1:2]
          ly[2] <- ly[1] + pfrac*(ly[2]-ly[1])
          ly[3] <- (ly[2]-ly[1])/nspec
          segments(x0 = niche.data[[ii]][,ci],
                   y0 = ly[1]+(ii-1)*ly[3], y1 = ly[1]+ii*ly[3], col = col[ii])
          ly <- ly[2] + ydens[,ii]/max(ydens)*(lims[2,ci]-ly[2])
          lines(xdens[,ii], ly, col = col[ii])
        }
      }
      if (ri > ci) {
        # lower triangle: point plots
        for(ii in 1:nspec) {
          points(niche.data[[ii]][,c(ci,ri)], col = col[ii], pch = 16)
        }
      }
      if (ri < ci) {
        # upper triangle: ellipses
        for(ii in 1:nspec) {
          for(jj in 1:nell[ii]) {
            lines(ell[[ii]][jj,which(D[1,] == ri & D[2,] == ci),,2:1], col = col[ii])
          }
        }
      }
      box()
      if(ci == niso) axis(side = 4, cex = cex) else axis(side = 4, labels = FALSE)
      if(ri == niso) axis(side = 1, cex = cex) else axis(side = 1, labels = FALSE)
      if(ri == 1) mtext(text = iso.names[ci], side = 3, line = 1, cex = cex)
      if(ci == 1) mtext(text = iso.names[ri], side = 2, line = 1, cex = cex)
    }
  }
  if(!missing(xlab)) {
    mtext(text = xlab, side = 1, outer = TRUE, line = 2.2, cex = 1.25 * cex)
  }
  legend(x = "topleft", legend = species.names, fill = col, bty = "n", cex = 0.9 * cex)
  par(opar) # reset par
}
```

Now we can rerun the code from the vignette to get the data that we want to plot:

```
library(nicheROVER)
data(fish) # 4 fish, 3 isotopes
aggregate(fish[2:4], fish[1], mean) # isotope means calculated for each species type here
# 2-d projections of 10 niche regions
clrs <- c("black", "red", "blue", "orange") # colors for each species
nsamples <- 10
fish.par <- tapply(1:nrow(fish), fish$species,
                  function(ii) niw.post(nsamples = nsamples, X = fish[ii,2:4]))

# format data for plotting function
fish.data <- tapply(1:nrow(fish), fish$species, function(ii) X = fish[ii,2:4])
```

Finally we call our custom `niche.plot()` implementation with the additional `cex` argument. Here I have set it to `1.1`, which will increase the size of all text by 10%.

```
niche.plot(niche.par = fish.par, niche.data = fish.data, pfrac = .05,
          iso.names = expression(delta^{15}*N, delta^{13}*C, delta^{34}*S),
            col = clrs, xlab = expression("Isotope Ratio (per mil)"), cex = 1.1)
```